# Class property that infers from optional constructor parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I have following scenario:

```js
class Dispatcher<R extends (...args: any) => any, T = undefined> {
    fn: R
    extra: T
    constructor(fn: R, extra?: T) {
        this.fn = fn;
        this.extra = extra;
    }
}

const test = new Dispatcher(() => {
    return true;
});

// TS type hinting should know that extra is undefined
test.extra;

const test2 = new Dispatcher(() => {
    return true;
}, {
    graphUrl: "/foo/"
});

// TS type hinting should know that extra exists and has a property graphUrl
test2.extra.graphUrl
```

In this case I want the `extra` class member to infer based on whether it was passed to the constructor. If I pass a boolean, it should be a boolean, if I pass a string, it should be a string, if I pass undefined, it should be undefined. Right now the inference works and `extra` properly types, but TS throws an error in the constructor code when I assign `this.extra = extra`. Strictly speaking that error makes sense because I'm assigning a type that can be undefined to a type that cannot. The problem is if I update the member definition to be `extra?: T` then the inference breaks because now it thinks extra is something like `string | undefined`, which is incorrect. The problem is the extra variable isn't actually "optional" it is the value that it was passed, that value may be undefined... that's different than optional.

```
Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.
```

If I fix the error in the constructor code, then the type inference stops working and I get something like `string | undefined` which isn't accurate. We **know** the type because it was passed to the constructor.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCWEAOYAuwAWBTATgHgCVosAPVLAOwBMYAKAOkbBwHMIAuaMCgTwEpoAXgB8XXgBpoAFSHQArtSwAzeBSxVRAbwBQ0PdCUVOBXftKocYTlNN7gAewoQLc4Kns5ah45POWA-NYCOvqh0KgYiPSGsoYA3LZhEVF%20YLKpCaEAvto52g5OqOFYzrJqAO5wiCjo2J60AiLQIfo4WKhyOBThOHJYCVl8CdrkzvQZ2vmOpaOoAExlWJUIyGiYuLQNQlqJbR1dPX0Dki16LJZIGACqOCCcAEQA9Er29o-3uUOTs3PjZJb0c5gS43ECTPRAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, generic types are not always inferred. Sometimes they are explicit. So typescript is guarding you against a case like:

```
new Dispatcher<() => boolean, string>(() => true)
```

Now according to the type of your class, this is a valid way to instantiate the class. But internally, `extra` will be assigned `undefined` when it should be a `string`.

---

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this without a type assertion, but you can at least make it safe to do the type assertion.

What we need to do is make the argument optional if `T` is undefined. And you can do that by making the function arguments a conditional type that resolves to a tuple.

```
class Dispatcher<R extends (...args: any) => any, T = undefined> {
    fn: R
    extra: T
    constructor(...args: T extends undefined ? [fn: R] : [fn: R, extra: T]) {
        const [fn, extra] = args
        this.fn = fn;
        this.extra = extra as T; // as T is still needed, sadly.
    }
}
```

Now if `T` is undefined, then the argument is missing from the arguments tuple. Else, `extra` is required and will need to be of type `T`.

The above case that broke without error, is now an error:

```
new Dispatcher<() => boolean, string>(() => true) // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
```

Here because `T` is `string`, then the second argument is required.

But these still work as expected:

```
new Dispatcher<() => boolean>(() => true) // fine
new Dispatcher<() => boolean, undefined>(() => true) // fine
new Dispatcher<() => boolean, string>(() => true, 'foobar') // fine
```

Typescript is still confused that `extra` is safe to assign, and I'm not really sure how to fix that. But at least now I believe it's impossible to get an unsupported type into `extra`, so the `as T` should be safe.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=68&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiCWEAOYAuwAWBTATgHgCVosAPVLAOwBMYAKAOkbBwHMIAuaMCgTwEpoAXgB8XXgBpoAFSHQArtSwAzeBSxVRAbwBQ0PdCUVOBXftKocYTlNN7gAewoQLc4Kns4GTVh2nEylDTyiipqVNAA-NAA2obGALrQnLFG0ASS5pbW8QI6+vnQDk6oMYYZZJaJglw+tgWoGIj0hrKGANx1+Q1NmWCyvVwwUh35AL7a49pqAO5wiCjo2Pi0AiLQAEb29iBY3MK0K0KiLlgCAPRnBqpYU1izCMhomLh4h2ub27sUkgpUytcaA6rY44OSnaAXK5qW73eZPJavYEbLY7biSZw4VQsfZvEFgyQAciUW3WzAJ50uoRuMLmj0WL1xyM+aOgGKxOKRJwpxBwOA86KwRXCzBY0EQ0BwWAAjnJ4JKqPRtErtEVnNByGrqjNaQtnp5GXl9JLUHIcBR1aCsB1RnwOtpIVIAMrqnhILDQRoUVBY1kYexyEDhADWFHsswaaH8Fj64t+-zC2g1qHovTtqpKSYATLJtQ9dUsgUdoIa9MbTeaTtbJCXoCxLEgMABVHAgTgAIjOxPsZzbE1tSodztQrvdnu9FFFED9AeDofDGEjA1IiFQMG44QXa+gSD5bpww9r9abLcTWGcmZTFTA9DrYAbzZAQA)

There may still be a better solution, though.

Comment: According to the playground this looks like a valid solution. Currently, we never manually pass types to the constructor we always use inferred types. I was worried we would need to default to manually passing them to be certain. Thanks for the solution.